# React returning empty state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I understand that useEffect() hook is supposed to fire on the first render. In my code, I am getting errors for not being able to use my States properties. This is because the State doesn't have the API data before the DOM renders. I guess I am just not understanding if I am missing something, but the console log shows that the questions array is empty twice before actually getting any data. If I am not trying to access the data anywhere, no data is thrown, but as soon as I try to use it, the code says that the data doesn't exist. I tried to use async but get the same error.

```
export default function Quiz(props) {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setQuestions(data.results))
    }, [])

    console.log(questions)
    return (

        <div>
            <div className="quiz--question">
                <h1>{questions.category}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`questions` is an array , so you need to iterate that to display the value. You can use map

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setQuestions(data.results);
        console.log(questions);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {questions.map((elem) => (
        <div className="quiz--question">
          <h1>{elem.category}</h1>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jznvfo?file=App.tsx)